# Dual space & orthogonal $F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}\subset(F_1 \cap F_2)^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, duality-theorems

> $E$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and $E^∗$ its dual.
>
> $F_1$ and $F_2$ is a subspace of $E$
>
> I would like to prove that $F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}\subset(F_1 \cap F_2)^{\perp}$

*I asked this question 12 hours ago, but with no answser and no comment, I've prefered to cancel the last one and to rewrite it correctly.*

**Is my proof correct?**

---

Let $F_1^{\perp}:=\bigg\{\gamma\in E^*, \quad \forall x\in F_1, \;\gamma(x)=0\bigg\}$ and $F_2^{\perp}:=\bigg\{\psi\in E^*, \quad \forall x\in F_2, \;\psi(x)=0\bigg\}$

$\varphi \in F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp},\iff\exists (\gamma,\psi)\in \left(F_1^{\perp}\times F_2^{\perp}\right), \forall x \in E \quad \varphi(x)=(\gamma+\psi)(x)$

We can deduce as well $\exists \varphi'\in F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}$ such that $\varphi'(x)=(\gamma-\psi)(x)$

Now let : $F :=\bigg\{x\in E\;| \quad \forall \phi \in (F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}), \;\phi(x)=0\bigg\}$ and any $\varphi \in F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}$

Thus

$\forall x\in F, \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l} \varphi(x)=0\\ \varphi'(x)=0\end{array}\right. \iff \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l} \gamma(x)+\psi(x)=0\\\gamma(x)-\psi(x)=0\end{array}\right.\iff \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l} 2\gamma(x)=0 \quad \color {red}{(1)}\\2\psi(x)=0 \quad \color {red}{(2)}\end{array}\right. $

Since $(1)\land (2)$ we deduce that $ \forall \varphi \in F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp},\;\forall x\in F,\quad \varphi(x)=0 \implies x\in F_1\cap F_2$

We can conclude $\varphi \in (F_1\cap F_2)^{\perp}\quad \square$

Comment: What is it you're asking? Whether your proof is correct? Be specific. Don't make us guess.

Comment: I would like to know if my proof is correct

Comment: First off, like a lot of beginning math students, you're vastly overusing quantifiers. Use words, like "Let $\phi\in F_1^{\perp}+F_2^{\perp}$". It makes your proofs much easier to read and is less likely to lead to nonsense.

Comment: Second, you don't need $\phi^\prime$ at all. You already know what $\gamma$ and $\psi$ do to $x$ based on what subspace of $E^*$ they are in.

Comment: I wanted to show that $$\gamma(x)+\psi(x)=0 \implies (\gamma(x)=0)\land(\psi(x)=0)$$

Comment: You don't need to prove that since $\gamma\in F_1^*$ and $\psi\in F_2^*$. What you're not very clear on is where $x$ is from. It should be an element of $F_1\cap F_2$.

Comment: $x$ is from $F$, then I deduce that $F\subset F_1\cap F_2$

Comment: That isn't good enough. $x$ must be an arbitrary element of $F_1\cap F_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten this a lot. There are a great deal of extraneous constructions that miss the main idea. Since you originally reference a dual space, I assume you are asking about dual spaces, not orthogonal complements and have answered accordingly; be careful, as they are not the same thing.

Let $\phi\in F_1^0+F_2^0$, where $S^0 = \{\rho\in E^* \ | \ \forall x\in S, \  \rho(x)=0 \}$ denotes the annihilator of $S$. (It looks like this is perhaps what you mean by your $S^\perp$ notation.) Then $\phi = \gamma + \psi \ $  for some $\gamma\in F_1^0, \psi\in F_2^0$. Now if $x\in F_1\cap F_2$, then $x\in F_1$ and $x\in F_2$, so
$$\phi(x) = (\gamma + \psi)(x) =\gamma(x) + \psi(x) = 0 + 0 = 0.$$
Hence, $\phi\in(F_1\cap F_2)^0$.

Comment: Understood, in my proof, $\varphi$ can be an element of $$F^{\perp}\backslash(F_1\cap F_2)^{\perp}$$ which is wrong

Comment: @Stu If this answers your questions, consider accepting it.

Comment: In french we call $F^{\perp}$ orthogonal of F :$$F^{\perp}:=\bigg\{\gamma\in E^*, \quad \forall x\in F, \;\gamma(x)=0\bigg\}$$

Comment: I won't accept for the moment, I need to see that deeper. But that help me a lot

Comment: @Stu In matrices, this makes sense since you can associate a linear functional with a row vector so that $\phi(x) = \phi x$. But this is more problematic when you add in the notion of inner product spaces. How do you refer to orthogonal complements $S^\perp = \{y\in E \ | \ \forall x\in S, \ \langle x, y \rangle = 0 \}$?

Comment: The annihilator$\newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}$ and the orthogonal complement are isomorphic anyway, because of the Riesz representation theorem.
$$F^o=\left\{\gamma\in E^*: \gamma(x)=0, \forall x\in F\right\} \cong \left\{v\in E: \inner{x}{v} = 0, \forall x\in F\right\} = F^\perp$$

Comment: @mechanodroid Of course, but given the confusion in the OPs original proof, playing too fast and loose with implied isomorphisms strikes me as dangerous.

Comment: @mechanodroid However, I do like your notation better, so I'll modify my answer accordingly.